# Is there an easy way to set one cell's specially formatted contents equal to another's?

Tags: excel, vba, fonts, colors, format

I would like to fill individual cells with "rich" text. By this I mean that the cells contain several newlines, bullet points, and individual words varying in font, color, size, italic, etc.

I would like the on `SelectionChange` event to set one cell's contents equal to everything that the target cell contains (colors, fonts, etc.).
Setting "`Range("A1").Value = Target.Value`" or "`Range("A1").Value = "=" & Target.Address`" doesn't work as none of the special cell formatting is added.

I have some ideas of a very complex way of achieving this by looping through each word, checking it's color, font, size, and adding that word with those attributes, but I want to believe there's a better way.
Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: copy paste: `Target.Copy Range("A1")`

Comment: @ScottCraner You say it like it's so obvious XD thanks